# public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent)

Tags: java

Что происходит в скобках? Например, когда используется метод:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
```

*moseEvent* ведет себя так, как будто это уже созданный объект класса *MouseEvent*. Им можно инициализировать другой объект. Использовать методы из класса, например:

```
mouseEvent.getX()
```

Аналогичных конструкций в языке много. Это круто. Но я нигде не могу найти даже названия этого. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А кто такие "Дужки"?

Comment: Виноват, скобки ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял смысл вашего вопроса, вас смущает то, что некоторые методы некоторых классов получают в качестве параметра готовые объекты, которые нигде в коде не создаются и не инициализируются.

Это так называемые "события" и их "слушатели". Этот механизм используется для передачи информации между разными программами или модулями или библиотеками, которые друг о друге ничего (или почти ничего) не знают, но при этом должны взаимодействовать. Например, когда вы нажимаете кнопку мыши в окне вашей программы, операционная система ничего не знает о том, как ваша программа устроена и что она должна делать по нажатию кнопки, но она (система) должна как-то сообщить вашей программе, что мышка нажата в такой-то точке.

Решается это примерно так: вы используете какую-то библиотеку для построения GUI (awt, swt, swing, или что-то еще в этом роде), в которой описаны классы графических компонентов (кнопка, меню и т. п). Когда вы создаете экземпляр такого класса (кнопку, которая будет отображаться в окне вашей программы), библиотека создает соответствующую штуку в ОС или в себе самой. При нажатии кнопки система вызывает скрытый от вас метод этой штуки. Дальше вы можете у этой штуки зарегистрировать слушатель - специальный класс, у которого есть метод типа mousePressed() или, скажем, keyPressed(), но который, в отличие от ОС и графической библиотеки, описан в вашей программе, знает про нее всё, что нужно, и может в ней сделать что-то осмысленное. Это примерно как подписка на новости - вы говорите "Извещай меня сразу, когда произойдет то-то и то-то".

Тогда после нажатия кнопки мышки система создает "событие" - объект, который содержит всю необходимую информацию о событии (координаты мыши, код клавиши, состояние клавиши "Ctrl" и т. п. - и вызывает ваш метод, который вы описали в своем слушателе, передавая ему это событие. Ваш метод анализирует содержимое события и выполняет соответствующие действия по управлению вашей программой. Вот примерно как-то так, если на пальцах.

Чтобы узнать больше, почитайте книжки по графическим библиотекам и их событиям ("модель событий в библиотеке AWT") или что-нибудь такое. Что помню навскидку: у Хорстмана есть про swing, у Экеля немножко про SWT, ну и есть куча отдельных книжек по GUI, напр. The Definitive Guide to SWT and JFace by Robert Harris and Rob Warner.

Answer (score 2):

То, что у вас есть - это функция. По сути функция может принимать параметры и возвращать значение. Вот это самое "в дужках" - параметры функции.

**Как это работает?**

Просто:

```
static void sayHiTo(String person) {
    System.out.println("Hi, " + person);
}
```

Это, собственно, функция, метод, как вам больше нравится. И здесь `person` - параметр функции. Он может быть любой, хоть `null`.

**Как параметр попадает в функцию и откуда берется?**

Функцию можно вызвать из другой функции, например:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    sayHiTo("Sasha");
}
```

Вывод будет: "Hi, Sasha".
Метод `main` - точка входа в программу, самая первая функция, которая вызывается при запуске. Из нее я вызываю функцию `sayHiTo` и передаю строку `"Sasha"` в качестве параметра `person`. Т.е. в функции `sayHiTo` к переданной строке я смогу обратится через `person`.

**Как можно поискать в интернете?**

"Функция", Вызов функции", "Параметры функции", "Передача параметров в функцию" (при этом слово "функция" можно заменять на "метод")

Comment: Вот это я и не могу понять "Как параметр попадает в функцию и откуда берется?"  Если бы было MouseEvent mouseEvent = new MouseEvent(Component source, int id, long when, int modifiers,
                      int x, int y, int xAbs, int yAbs,
                      int clickCount, boolean popupTrigger, int button); public void mousePressed( mouseEvent){} То так понятно. Но создание объекта класса с таким конструктором... Понимаю что что-то его создает.

Comment: Человек, видимо, о событиях спрашивает - не может понять, кто их создает и откуда они попадают к слушателям, когда никто в коде этих слушателей не вызывает :)